# Django using global variables

Tags: python, django

I believe this question can be applied beyond the scope of Django, but Django is all I know: how to handle global 'resource' variables?

I am concurrently working on a testing framework for this [tutorial project](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing#locallibrary_tests) and finding myself copy-pasting field labels and help text to ensure their validity. Going forward, anytime I need to modify the label, I need to manually modify it in my testing framework as well which goes against basic programming principles. For example,

```
# My ModelForm class in /my/path/models.py
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_field(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data[<my_field>]
        ...
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

        fields = [<field_a>, <field_b>, ...] # copy-paste
        labels = {<field_a>: <label_a>, ...} # copy-paste
        help_texts = {<field_a>: <help_text_a>, ...} # copy-paste
----

# Corresponding SimpleTestCase in /my/path/test_forms.py
class MyFormTest(SimpleTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.form = MyForm()

    def test_field_a_form_label(self):
        expected = <label_a> # copy-paste
        fl = self.form.fields[<field_a>].label # copy-paste

        self.assertTrue(fl is None or fl == expected)

    ...
```

In Android, your project contains a 'resource' directory which has all the static values (help text, titles, etc) used throughout the project. This directory can then be accessed from anywhere through [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context), creating a single source of truth.

What is the recommended approach in web development for creating a single source of truth for resource variables like labels and help text?

Comment: The real question is: **what are you testing with your label tests**? The Django Forms API? Honestly, it does not make sense for me to test the label of each field. You could have a single source of truth by not testing this and having only one value written in the form code. Alternatively, if you store field labels globally like in Android, your tests will ALWAYS pass because both values will come from the same place. This will just make your test obsolete.

Comment: I was just following along with the mozilla tutorial project, but the question can be applied to any other static variable. The question is, what is the best location to define such variables? Do I just make global variables in my forms.py module or define them per class or?

Comment: You could have a separate "resource" module for this where you define globals. All modules are singletons.

Comment: Is that standard practice? I couldn't find a recommended approach for this (probably because I wasn't wording my query correctly)

Comment: I think that having single source of truth in your case is not what you want. When testing something you always need to have **expected** and **actual** values, otherwise the test can be reduced to this statement: `assert True == True`. I know that you might want to reduce code duplication in this case, but I'm afraid it's not possible. Like I said before, I don't think that testing label definitions is worth the effort because you can make the mistake in the test, too. The usual practice when testing forms is to test validation logic. IMO, this is the most important part.

Comment: @vinkomlacic The code actually does test that the expected `label_a` matches the actual `self.form.fields[<field_a>].label`. Problem is, in the tutorial I copy-pasted `label_a` from `models.py` to `test_forms.py`. What I would expect is having say a `resources.py` module with a global dictionary containing a `FORM_LABELS = {'my_form_field_a' : my_form_label_a}` pair, which I can then use to both assign it in the model: `labels = [resources.FORM_LABELS]`. And use for test verification: `self.assertEqual(resources.FORM_LABELS['my_form_field_a'], self.form.fields['my_form_field_a'].label)`